# md_raid10 hangs - possible reasons?

Tags: linux, software-raid

I have been researching the possible cause for this sort of behaviour:

```
INFO: task md1_raid10:240 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[123491.284102]       Not tainted 4.18.20 #1
[123491.284105] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[123491.284109] md1_raid10      D    0   240      2 0x80000000
[123491.284116] Call Trace:
[123491.284132]  ? __schedule+0x421/0x8c0
[123491.284138]  ? preempt_count_add+0x67/0xb0
[123491.284144]  schedule+0x3c/0x90
[123491.284162]  md_super_wait+0x69/0xa0 [md_mod]
[123491.284173]  ? remove_wait_queue+0x60/0x60
[123491.284184]  md_update_sb.part.61+0x4ad/0x900 [md_mod]
[123491.284197]  md_check_recovery+0x310/0x530 [md_mod]
[123491.284205]  raid10d+0x64/0x15a0 [raid10]
[123491.284211]  ? __schedule+0x429/0x8c0
[123491.284216]  ? schedule+0x46/0x90
[123491.284220]  ? schedule_timeout+0x1f7/0x370
[123491.284224]  ? preempt_count_add+0x67/0xb0
[123491.284229]  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x25/0x50
[123491.284232]  ? preempt_count_add+0x67/0xb0
[123491.284243]  ? md_thread+0x120/0x160 [md_mod]
[123491.284252]  md_thread+0x120/0x160 [md_mod]
[123491.284258]  ? remove_wait_queue+0x60/0x60
[123491.284263]  kthread+0xf8/0x130
[123491.284272]  ? md_rdev_init+0xc0/0xc0 [md_mod]
[123491.284277]  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
[123491.284281]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40
```

All I have found, including stackexchange points to some harsh server conditions under heavy system loads. In my case it occurs in a system which hosts 4HHS in Raid1+0 configuration, that are bright new, actually the system has been set up just yesterday and contains virtually no data. The hangup occurred during listing the home directory (which contains just 10 files) via an SMB client.

The disks on this system are encrypted with dm_crypt. No LVM is used.

```
root@stasiek1:/home/lacki# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid10] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md1 : active raid10 sdd3[3] sdb3[1] sda3[0] sdc3[2]
      7225882624 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 1/54 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid10 sdd2[3] sda2[0] sdc2[2] sdb2[1]
      585674752 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 3/5 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>


root@stasiek1:/home/lacki# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 29 22:59:44 2018
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 585674752 (558.54 GiB 599.73 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 292837376 (279.27 GiB 299.87 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Jan 29 22:14:24 2019
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : stasiek1:0  (local to host stasiek1)
           UUID : d12a1437:ab040229:dbc0f4bf:796a97dd
         Events : 768

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda2
       1       8       18        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb2
       2       8       34        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc2
       3       8       50        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd2


root@stasiek1:/home/lacki# mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Dec 29 23:00:13 2018
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 7225882624 (6891.14 GiB 7399.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3612941312 (3445.57 GiB 3699.65 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Jan 29 22:13:37 2019
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : stasiek1:1  (local to host stasiek1)
           UUID : bdf36256:191923e1:01254e05:8bc447c9
         Events : 7357

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda3
       1       8       19        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb3
       2       8       35        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc3
       3       8       51        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd3
```

System: Kernel: 4.18. Debian stretch

Comment: -1 | For you don't provide us with any information about the array at hand.

Comment: can you show us the return of `cat /proc/mdstat` and `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md[x]`

Comment: did you check if there were any hardware error with your disks ?

Comment: No hardware error I guess. Smart status is clean. And these are bright new disks fresh from the store.

Comment: "For you don't provide us with any information about the array at hand." - I written in the original question that I do not know what info is necessary offering to provide more details by request. But this was removed by I presume administrator. So I assume it is customary to ask for more details, and I am confused with your remark.

Comment: Did you check SMART, or are you (wrongly) assuming that new disks = perfect disks? I've had DOA ones before (not many, but one or two).

Comment: Smart status is clean. Kernel:  4.18.  Debian stretch

Comment: Please add that to your question. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More comment than answer, but too long for a comment.

This is probably a kernel bug. Kernel issues like these are unfortunately rather common, a recent example is [md: fix raid10 hang issue caused by barrier](https://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&m=154869461015401&w=2).

There is not much you can do about kernel bugs, if you're not a kernel dev and don't want to dive in :-)

- see if others had the same issue with that kernel version and might have found a workaround [like disabling blk_mq](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1827232#p1827232)
- try the very latest kernel [or an older one in case the bug was a recent addition, then perhaps [help bisect the issue](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/bug-bisect.html)
- check the mailing list for patches and try those
- check your distro's forums and bugtracker
- report to [the linux-raid mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-raid) yourself so the issue may be investigated and fixed properly

And then it's just a matter of hope / luck - and also a question if this issue affects many people or, for some weird reason, only you.

If it's only you, then even though it seems like a kernel bug, doing a clean install on new hardware might still "fix" it. A lot of bugs are fixed this way, without determining the root cause properly (because doing so requires special skills, and time...).

Comment: I have been trying now kernel 4.9 for few days an no problem. However, this is not conclusive: the bug above took 2-7 days to trigger. Last time I tried to cause in on purpose - I copied several tens of TB back and forth. No problem. Few hours later simple listing directory content caused it. Anyway  I appreciate your comment/response very much.